# Проверка ввода данных на языке Си

Tags: c

Мне нужно сделать проверку входных данных на число. Если пользователь вводит не число, то программа его просит ввести данные заново.

Программа реагирует на входные данные по-разному.
Если я ввожу "qwe" и потом введу "1", то программа все равно попросит ввести данные заново, но если я введу "11", то все будет нормально. И так далее - чем больше букв я ввел, тем больше нужно чисел, чтобы программа не потребовала вводить заново.
Помогите, пожалуйста, я не понимаю, почему оно так работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Введите n\n");
  char n[5];  
  a:;
  scanf("%s", n);
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 5){
    if ((n[i] < 48 || n[i] > 57) && n[i] != '\0'){
      printf("Введите число заново\n");
      goto a;
    }
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ранее введённые данны остаются в массиве. Поэтому ваша проверка в цикле их обнаруживает. / Когда нашли '\0' - нужно выходить из цикла.

Comment: Массив `n[5]` позволяет ввести _четыре_ символа. Последним, пятым, будет '\0'.

Comment: @MALIS 

"*Если я ввожу "qwe" и потом введу "1", то программа все равно попросит ввести данные заново*" - ну и правильно! Какое же это число?!  "*но если я введу 11, то все будет нормально*" - а что же ненормального в числе 11 ?!

Comment: @Sergey, вы ничего не поняли :)

Comment: @MALIS "вы ничего не поняли" - вполне допускаю. Может быть потому, что вы **так** объяснили.